# Explicit scrollbar option for code blocks

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, user-experience

While on the mobile site, I've encountered a UX issue multiple times.

---

It's typically easy to determine when horizontal scrolling is present:

[image: Horizontal scrolling required]

But, looking at the picture below:

[image: Complete?]

It seems as if the code block we're seeing is complete - it's a valid declaration for that language.

However...

[image: Horizontal scrolling possible]

There is content beyond what is visible.

---

## This issue interferes with my contributions

**The question wasn't comprehensible until I scrolled horizontally.** *I didn't think to scroll until another user came along and suggested a duplicate.*

At first, I figured the asker may have been confused, which is common. However, after the suggested duplicate, I finally realized there was information I didn't see.

I scrolled. Felt stupid. Wasted time.

---

## I don't want the app

Shouldn't have to justify myself. But for those who are curious, some of the devices I use are limited in space.

I don't want to have to install the app everytime I want to contribute, just to uninstall once I require the extra space.

Most of my devices have browser support, hence why I prefer the mobile site over the app.

---

## Should I test every code block I see?

My only current solutions would be:

1. Consistently use desktop mode, which impacts the simplicity of reading posts (forced to zoom in & scroll)
2. Try to scroll every code block I come across

Both of these solutions require me to "*jump through hoops*". Not many hoops, but enough to harm UX.

---

## Optional explicit scroll bars

The images above speak for themselves.

If the scrollbar was visible, this wouldn't have been an issue. There are currently no options to allow explicit scroll bars.

---

## Let us choose

Hiding scroll bars is common. However, in some cases, it affects UX negatively.

An option would allow those who encounter the issue to enhance UX, while ensuring those who *don't* encounter the issue won't be forced to see them until they manually scroll.